# What is best way to encrypt password to store in mySQL DB using Java?

Tags: java, mysql, encryption

What is the best way to encrypt string password that will be stored in DB? I wanna to let users to create accounts using my desktop app and then save that in table in DB, and after acceptance by administrator this accounts (from table) will be created mySQL DB, using CREATE USER & GRANT USER.
Thanks for help.

Comment: That's not a very good idea. Why do they need to have an actual USER in the database?

Comment: Do you think better solution is to store all users in DB table, and check while login to "my system" that login&password are identical with that stored in table and after that let them use app? And when they wanna do INSERT/SELECT or other query use connection to mysql db with one  login&password (the one that i've got already created ) which will be hardcoded in java project?

Comment: Oh you have a desktop app. That makes it more complicated, since you shouldn't really be providing a direct connection to the database, but use the facilities provided by your server to perform different tasks. That just means more work for you, but it avoids the potential security risks of a DB port open for the world.

Comment: To encrypt on 1 location and decrypt on another and prevent local decryption (so that the password is save for the time being) you will need a public/private key structure